# Datatables deferred loading serverside filter delay

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables (https://datatables.net/) and I have enabled deferred loading. What it simply has to do, load 10 results (or something, it's not that important for now). Then, when you click on a new page, it has to get X next results (there can be lots of results so I don't want to load all data at once).

Now, there's one problem. If I search, after every character it sends an AJAX request, resulting in lots of AJAX requests. But what it should do is:

- Load 10 items
- You type
- After last typed character, wait 2 seconds, then fire the AJAX request

I got this code:

```
var dataTable = $('#editor').dataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: baseUrl + '/ajax/getWebpages',
        dataSrc: '',
        type: 'POST'
    },
    deferLoading: 10,
    serverSide: true,
    searchDelay: 2000,
}).on('search.dt', function()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        return true;
    }, 2000);
});
```

I know the return true is probably wrong, I really don't know how to get my idea to work. I searched for a long time but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah. But this doesn't do what I want; instead, it just waits X amount of milliseconds before making the request, which means if you type 5 character, it will wait and still do all those requests. But I found the answer already.

Comment: what you are looking is called "debounce" have a look for it

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

I had to put my code in `initComplete`, like:

```
var dataTable = $('#editor').dataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: baseUrl + '/ajax/getWebpages',
        dataSrc: '',
        type: 'POST'
    },
    deferLoading: 57,
    serverSide: true,
    searchDelay: 2000,
    columns: [ ],
    initComplete: function()
    {
        var api = dataTable.api();

        $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind('.DT').bind('keyup.DT', function(e)
        {
            var value = this.value;

            clearTimeout(timer);

            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                api.search(value).draw();
            }, 400);
        });
    }
});
```

Explaination:

- You type something, this function clears the timeout stored in `timer` (a 'global' variable in my case)
- If you stop typing, the timeout won't be cleared (since it'll only be cleared when you type)
- The last timeout of 400 milliseconds is still active, so after 400 milliseconds after the last character typed it'll execute.

`initComplete` is an event called after dataTables have been initialized. 
`.unbind('.DT')` removes the keyup event so it won't automatically call the AJAX requests.
`api.search` does the search.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and explanation. I've been searching for this feature and don't understand why the normal behaviour is constant polling...

Comment: @PatrickWinkelmayer and future readers: the creator/maintainer of datatables is aware it makes more sense but hasn't got around to changing it but will update this thread https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33028/searchdelay-for-server-side-issue. Some good alternatives in there also.

Comment: Is there a better solution to this since this solution was posted?